Allowing deployment of pods on AWS EKS where total requests is greater than total capacity available on the cluster
We are currently using AWS EKS instances to deploy our pods. What we are seeing is that typically our actual utilization is much less than our total pod requests. The reason for that is because as of now our application is not being used as frequently as expected.
Can we set overcommit factor in EKS based on the actual utlization so that we can have a fewer number of EC2 instances to accomodate these pods.

That sounds like your Pod resource requests are too high and you should change those.  The requests are only used for scheduling decisions.  If your Pod requests, say, 2 GiB of memory but it only needs 512 MiB to run most of the time, a high resource limit might be appropriate but setting requests higher causes space to be wasted.  The difference between requests and limits is fundamentally the overcommit you're asking about.


...our actual utilization is much less than our total pod requests.

You can request the minimum resources for your pod:
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 0.1
    memory: 100Mi


Can we set overcommit factor...

You can specify a limit to prevent it from going overboard.
  limits:
    cpu: 1
    memory: 1Gi

Adjust the values above accordingly, you can find more details here.

For the autoscaling of the pods you can use HPA and for the nodes part you can use karpenter or cluster autoscaler, HPA will help you to scale your deployment based on the CPU usage or memory usage, CA or Karpenter will help you to scale your nodes count based on your pods count.

Thanks for the reply, My question was that without autoscaling nodes can I schedule pods whose total requests is greater than the node capacity by allowing overcommiting of resources ?
